# 'Dictionary' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

```
let df = dict["forms"] as? Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>
    let dfs = dict["forms"] as? Array<Dictionary<Dictionary<String,Any>>>
```

The second line is what produces the error. I am uncertain of the correct syntax here. I am trying to grab a dictionary inside the dictionary. I don't see why this syntax doesn't work

Comment: `[[String:Any]]` and `[[String:[String:Any]]]` are probably easier to read and more swifty

Comment: @luk2302 So is this a more updated syntax version?

Comment: I think those were there from the beginning https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you! It works. And it's a cleaner solution. I'll look over that documentation too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the dictionary inside a dictionary you need to specify the key type of the outer dictionary. Assuming it's `String`, use

```
Array<Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Any>>>
//               ^^^^^^
```

or

```
[[String : [String : Any]]]
```